# MySQL Error unknown variable LOG_OUTPUT

Tags: mysql, linux, logfile

I am new to MySQL,I want to output the MySQL log file into both table and file,But I keep getting an unknown system variable.
how can I fix it.

```
SET GLOBAL Log_output='TABLE,FILE';
```

What I want is to output the (mysql.log) to a table in order to monitor user behavior of a database to detect abnormal behavior.

Thanks in advance for your time and effort..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `my.cnf` instead to have more control and details. In this case review the config file using command `$ cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf`. If there was result like below:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

then try to navigate to referred directory: `cd /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/`

Edit the configuration file `vi mysqld.cnf`, then put the following lines below the **mysqld**:

```
[mysqld]

log-output=TABLE
long-query_time=0.0001
```